# Is there a way to clean up this code to make it more efficient and not look so messy?

Tags: python, performance, twilio, mms

I have 2 .jpg pictures that I am sending. They both are called as follows: 'wow1', 'wow2'.  The code below works when I send it, but it doesn't look very pretty. How can I clean this up?

```
for n in range (1,3):
    address = 'http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow'
    extension = '.jpg'
    picture =str(n)
    p = str(address+picture+extension)
    media_url = p
```

If I give it a print function, it prints as follows:

> http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow1.jpg
>   http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow2.jpg

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey @arekenny3, are you using python3 or python 2?

Comment: I think [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would have been better suited to answer a question like this

Comment: What does this question have to do with the `twilio` and `mms` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python 3.6, you can also use Literal String Interpolation(f-strings)

```
address = [f'http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow{n}.jpg' for n in range(1,3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
for n in range (1,3):
    media_url = 'http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow{0}.jpg'.format(n)
```

Comment: Alternatively, if @arekenny3 is using python 3.6 or greater he can use fstrings.

for n in range (1,3):
    media_url = f"http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow{n}.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
for n in range (1,3):
    address = 'http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow%d.jpg'%(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the results (i.e. ***addresses***) it using a list comprehension.

```
my_list = ['http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow{}.jpg'.format(n) for n in range(1,3)]
```

or we can use f-strings (Introduced in Python 3.6)

```
my_list = [f'http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow{n}.jpg' for n in range(1,3)]


# print(my_list) for testing purposes
```

Doing the same within a for loop:

```
for n in range(1,3):
    address = f'http://exampleaddress.com/rowdycode/wow{n}.jpg'
    # print (address)
```